# Login Logout Scripts issue with Php On Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, logout

I entered username='admin' pw='admin'on my login.php that’s values true on mysqladmin

and it stops in check_login.php, after I can't see anything .

Here is the codes

check_login.php

```
      <?php
define(DOC_ROOT,dirname(__FILE__)); // To properly get the config.php file
$username = $_POST['username']; //Set UserName
$password = $_POST['password']; //Set Password
$msg ='';
if(isset($username, $password)) {
    ob_start();
    include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($username);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA('$mypassword')";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
        session_register("admin");
        session_register("password");
        $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;
        header("location:admin.php");
    }
    else {
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}
else {
    header("location:login.php?msg=Please enter some username and password");
}
?>
```

and

admin.php

```
<?php
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
if(!session_is_registered("admin")){ //If session not registered
header("location:login.php"); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Welcome To Admin Page Demonstration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome To Admin Page <?php echo ADMIN /*Echo the username */ ?></h1>
    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> <!-- A link for the logout page -->
    <p>Put Admin Contents</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried something for find the error I wrote echo"asdasd" on my check_login.php and I saw "asdasd" untill 21. Line that's line starting with session_register(...). I think here is my problem. But I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Look into enabling error reporting in PHP. It will make your life so much easier and give you detailed error messages: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php Also, check your php log files on the server. It will tell you exactly what the problem is. Oh, and `session_register` is deprecated - use `$_SESSION` instead

Comment: include your config.php too let us see it

Comment: `session_register()` is deprecated as of 5.3 I do believe.

Comment: `session_register() Warning This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.` http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php

Comment: ^--« ... and there ya go ;-)

Comment: thanks a lot for answers here is config.pgp $dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUser = 'root';
$dbPass = 'root';
$dbName = 'db2';
$dbC = mysqli_connect($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName)
        or die('Error Connecting to MySQL DataBase');

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` instead of just making it die.

Answer (score 1):

One of two problems...

You're defining `$username` and then doing `session_register("admin")`.

Or ... you're running on PHP 5.4 which [no longer implements](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) `session_register()`.

instead of

```
session_register("password")
```

use

```
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have still problems, i cant check to login admin page.I can open admin.php without username and pw.

Here is my changed check_login.php

```
<?php


error_reporting(E_ALL); 
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
define(DOC_ROOT,dirname(__FILE__)); // To properly get the config.php file
$username = $_POST['username']; //Set UserName
$password = $_POST['password']; //Set Password
$msg ='';
if(isset($username, $password)) {
    ob_start();
    include(DOC_ROOT.'/config.php'); //Initiate the MySQL connection
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $myusername = stripslashes($username);
    $mypassword = stripslashes($password);
    $myusername = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $myusername);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbC, $mypassword);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM login_admin WHERE user_name='$myusername' and user_pass=SHA('$mypassword')";
    $result=mysqli_query($dbC, $sql);
    // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
    if($count==1){
        // Register $myusername, $mypassword and redirect to file "admin.php"
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;
        error_reporting(E_ALL); 
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        $_SESSION['name']= $myusername;
        header("location:admin.php");
    }
    else {
        $msg = "Wrong Username or Password. Please retry";
        header("location:login.php?msg=$msg");
    }
    ob_end_flush();
}
else {
    header("location:login.php?msg=Please enter some username and password");
}
?>
```

here is the admin.php

```
   <?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
session_start(); //Start the session
define(ADMIN,$_SESSION['name']); //Get the user name from the previously registered super global variable
// if(!isset($_SESSION['admin']));{ //If session not registered
if( isset($_SESSION['admin']) && $_SESSION['admin'] == '0' ){

header('location:login.php'); // Redirect to login.php page
}
else //Continue to current page

header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Welcome To Admin Page Demonstration</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome To Admin Page <?php echo ADMIN /*Echo the username */ ?></h1>
    <p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p> <!-- A link for the logout page -->
    <p>Put Admin Contents</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.